# How do I relate the build file line number of an error to my development files?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a react native application built using Expo. I have an error that occurs only in the build version on Android devices. I believe it has something to do with redux-persist but I'm unsure. 
Using react's componentDidCatch() and a cloud function, I have been able to capture on what line of the built code the error is happening. However, I don't know how to relate that back to the code in my editor.

componentDidCatch() returns this:

```
{ line: 1459,
    column: 859,
    sourceURL: '/data/user/0/.....' },
  { componentStack: '\n    in N\n    in n\n    in D\n    in B\n    in c\n    in s\n    in RCTView\n    in n\n    in v\n    in RCTView\n    in RCTView\n    in c' }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can reach to `index.android.bundle` file from your project directory:  `android/app/build/generated/assets/react/release/index.android.bundle`